# Toolkit / tool for PDF checking?

Tags: windows, linux, pdf

Looking for a command line tool for Windows / linux environment that can check a PDF file for any errors (not for repairing).

Answer (score 2):

With Ghostscript on Windows use:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
   -o nul ^
   -sDEVICE=nullpage ^
    c:/path/to/input.pdf
```

On Linux use:

```
gs \
   -o /dev/null \
   -sDEVICE=nullpage \
    c:/path/to/input.pdf
```

All errors or warnings encountered by Ghostscript it will print to stdout/stderr.

It will **NOT** convert your original file, just report what would happen if you actually *did* a real conversion. This serves a quite good chcker... just as you wanted it. Just use the [latest Ghostscript version](http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/) (current one is 9.02).

Answer (score 1):

One thing I use on Linux is pdfinfo, which comes with the poppler package.

For normal PDF files, it gives me about 15 lines of information on the file.  For the broken PDF files I have, or non-PDF files, it spits out errors before giving the 15 lines of information, if any.  I can pipe the output to a "grep ^Error" if I just want the errors.  Or if I so wanted I could just modify the source code to just output errors.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure about that, but i think that ghostscript can be of use.
It works with PS and with PDF, and I heard that it is very strict.